# How do design a method that can query the DB and return different type that implements the same interface?

Tags: c#, generics, xsd, dapper

### Context

We are developing a software for our Government, the government releases some PDF's describing an XML file structure and their respective XSD. So, we generate all the POCO classes we will need from the XSD's and everything is going fine.

The Government releases too many versions of the same XSD and our software will need to handle all the different versions. All the versions are very similar, but little different. Some fields are added, others excluded, some string support four characters in one version and just three in others and so on.

My question is how to design my software to handle all the different versions simultaneously.

For now, I am generating the POCO classes from the XSD and storing different versions in different namespaces, like this example of same S1000 class from `ver1` and `ver2` namespaces:

```
namespace GPLayoutsESocial.ver1.S1000
{
    public partial class S1000 : IEventoEsocial
    {
         //...
    }
}

namespace GPLayoutsESocial.ver2.S1000
{
    public partial class S1000 : IEventoEsocial
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

This way (and using a Factory Method), I can get specific version easily.

### The Problem

I need to develop a method that query the database to fullfil the properties of my POCO but I dont want to create one method for each version (because they will be very similar) and I dont know the version i will need to fullfill.
In fact, i need a method that receives the version by parameter, queries the database and return the correct POCO class version, the calling could be something like this:

```
var result = Fullfil_S1000(int version);
```

What to implement inside the `Fullfil_S1000` method? I am thinking in the folowing aproach:

```
 public ??? ObterDadosEvento(int version, ...)
 {
    using (IDbConnection cn = ConexaoGPG.Connection)
    {
        cn.Open();
        item = cn.Query<ver1.S1000>(" SELECT * FROM... }).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    // If the version == 1:
    // - Executes the query and return the POCO from "version1"

    // If the version == 2:
    // - Runs the query to get the "version 1", 
    // - Pass the version1 POCO to another method that updates only the fields changed in the version2 and 
    // - returns the "version2" POCO.

    // If the version == 3:
    // - Runs the query to get the "version 1", 
    // - Pass the version1 POCO to another method that updates only the fields changed in the version3 and 
    // - returns the "version3" POCO.

    // And so on...
```

How can i implement the described steps without the need of hard-code to handle each version?

Comment: Maybe a Decorator Pattern? I could add behaviors for each version, so if the version is `version 3` I can execute the main step and add two behaviours, one for version 2, one for version 3.

Comment: Or maybe a Chain Of Responsability, where each handler handle one version?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of a "clean" way to maintain one C# / XmlSerialization codebase that deals with multiple XSD structures, but it's a common enough problem.

If the XSDs really are similar, an inelegant but very maintainable approach may be to create and maintain your own XSD which represents a union of the options.  Then use text-based pre-processing and post-processing to convert between your format and the government's.  For example, substituting out XML namespaces.

The pre- and post- processing rules can typically just be collections of RegEx find/replace string pairs, grouped by version.  Or (for example) they can be in the form of XSLT files.